# Flutter application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Here is the import statement in 'main.dart'

```
import 'package:firestoreflutter/lib/ui/listveiw_note.dart';
```

and i can confirm that the file exists! However when i go to compile i get the error message:

```
Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not 
be established.
The following Dart file:
/home/jedaa/workspace/flutter_apps/studio/firestoreflutter/lib/main.dart
refers, in an import, to the following library: /home/jedaa/workspace/flutter_apps/studio/firestoreflutter/lib/lib/ui/listveiw_note.dart

Unfortunately, that library does not appear to exist on your file system.
```

Of course it does not exist, and the import statement does not say to look there .. viz: /lib/lib/ui !!!!

What is going on here?? Can somebody help me out as i cannot find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what `listveiw_note.dart` is, but are you sure it's not supposed to be `listview_note.dart` (with `i` and `e` swapped)?

Comment: Yes!! ... i before e except after c .. i c it now! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error in your import, this is the correct import

```
import 'package:firestoreflutter/lib/ui/listview_note.dart'
```

Please confirm. Thanks

Comment: Yes .. well spotted!! .. thankyou. However, now no projects at all will compile any more ... in AS or Intellij?? My latest SO post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532810/error-launching-application-on-android-sdk-built-for-x86 ... *sigh*

Comment: you are welcome, I think you can upvote this answer, because it solved your library missing problem. And I am looking into your new problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the lib in your import. This is because `firestoreflutter` automatically puts in a lib for you, causing the two libs to be seen in the error

Comment: Okay .. thanks. When i get my editors back on line i will do just that!

Answer (score 0):

You can try "sudo chmod -R 775 xxx/studio" to the entire studio