# Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

There are a least a dozen previously compiled and running flutter applets that suddenly will not compile under Android Studio or Intellij.

Even if i build a new default Flutter app i get this crash error:

Clearly something has changed .. plugins/dependencies have been upgraded/updated and the .gradle and .idea directories removed ... and projects rebuilt .. but nothing gets past this:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
cmd: Can't find service: activity
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
adb: failed to install/home/jedaa/workspace/flutter_apps/studio/flutter_apprescue/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
```

Comment: Have you specified the launch activity or service inside your `manifest.xml` file?

Comment: No ... should I? I am just trying to get the default flutter app to run out of the box.

Comment: @shizhen can you please provide an example or link on how to add that activity to the manifest?

Comment: "Cold boot" works

Answer (score 76):

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)
3. Open emulator
4. Try to run app

Comment: I would add close project and reopen. Thanks

Comment: Did this and everything started working again. Thanks.

Comment: In my case tho, I didn't had to wipe the data.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar error when trying to run my flutter application. What I did was:

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Press on the small arrow (next to the pen) corresponding to your preferred device
3. Select "Cold boot now"
4. Wait for the emulator to open and boot
5. Run your application

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was my configuration but it works now.

Answer (score 15):

Changing the emulator to cold boot rather than quick boot also seemed to resolve the problem. Rather than a complete wipe.

It's in advanced settings > emulated performance > boot option when editing a device in AVD.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

no need to change system variables or adb.
it's not adb or emulator error.
**change your device or emulator and check again!!!**

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity                                                                                       

   android:exported="true">                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
                                                                        
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using adb through command line:

```
<C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\>adb -s yourdeviceID install -r build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk
```

you can follow this for more explanation: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8605

Thanks

Comment: Thanks shizhen ... but i got impatient and reinstalled everything .. which has not worked!!! .. you can read about it here if inclined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552232/unable-to-locate-a-development-device-again

Answer (score 0):

I  was installing the application on BlueStacks Emualtor and I resolve this issues using these steps:-

1. Go to Setting.
2. Then Go To Advance
3. Then turn on Android Debug Bridge(ADV)

Using these steps we can resolve this issues on BlueStack.

Answer (score 0):

My fix in file "build.gradle"

```
defaultConfig {
    ......
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

choose the devices marked by "cold boot"

[image: choose the devices marked by "cold boot"]

Answer (score -1):

AOA There, you can go simply to your project App-level build.gradle file me change your minSdkVersion to the updated version. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Please, attach the image in the answer instead to add a link to it. Also, your answer is lacking context explaining how the suggested solution actually fixes OP problem, please add more context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).