# ADB exited with exit code 1| Error launching application on sdk gphone x86 64

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I want to run my flutter project on my pixel 6 pro emulator. As soon as I run my project without debugging, I am getting this error:

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install D:\Flutter\food_delivery_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on sdk gphone x86 64.
```

I have looked similar question and tried some of the solutions, but it didn't work out - [ADB exited with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367108/adb-exited-with-exit-code-1)

I run these commands on my terminal :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Also I didn't get any errors regarding flutter doctor prompt:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1848], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default
      components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Storage is not filled yet.
Does someone knows what might be causing to this problem ?

Comment: Can you show your pubspec.yaml file and package name?

Comment: @RahulPandey Here is my pubspec.yaml file :
    'name: food_delivery_app
    description: A new Flutter project.
    publish_to: 'none'
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0'
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

name: food_delivery_app'

Comment: Sorry can you tell me one last thing.... navigate to Android/app/src/build.gradle file and tell me the `application Id` which is inside defaultConfig?

Comment: @RahulPandey 
    applicationId "com.example.food_delivery_app"

Comment: Everything looks fine so I just a suggestion try this if it works otherwise  I can't help much 
`1.Open AVD Manager`
`2.Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)`
`3.Open emulator`
`Try to run app`

Comment: @RahulPandey 
Wiping the data from emulator worked for me. But sometimes it is not working as I expected. Thanks. If there any solutions you know I will be happy to hear it.

Comment: Sure if I came to know a definite solution I'll let you know !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53532810/150978